# Can not get microphone to work

Tags: alsa, microphone, ubuntu-mate

[image]I have 2 microphones, one with my Lifecam and another one.

But I can not use the non-Lifecam  microphone?

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HD5000 [Microsoft® LifeCam HD-5000], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How can I use that one?

[image]

Comment: I have got the microphone working but it has static.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the microphone connector in the back does not always work.

If I remove it and re-connect, it works.

The front connector works fine.